# <p:imageSwitch> tag for imageslideshow

Tags: jsf, primefaces, imageswitcher

I am new to Jsf and my requirement is to fetch list of images names(like n1.jpg,n2.jpg..etc for id=1 and n3.jpg,n4.jpg,n5.jpg...etc for id=2) for particular id from database, append it to "resources/Images/" and display slide show with pause and resume button in browser. I am using primefaces 4.0, jsf 2.2, mojarra 2.2.0. I am implementing the slide show task using p:imageswitch but the images are not displayed. Can anyone help me to trace my mistake, I am not getting any error also.
The following is the xhtml code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{imageBean.selectedmp}" id="ulist">
      <f:selectItems value="#{imageBean.dropdownValues}"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 <h:commandButton value="Display Images" action="#{imageBean.executeQueryImages}" />
    <div id="slider">
      <p:imageSwitch  widgetVar="switcher2" effect="none"         slideshowSpeed="100" slideshowAuto="false" >
         <ui:repeat value="#{imageBean.images}" var="image">
             <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{image}" />
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:imageSwitch>  
  </div>
```

This is my java code for executing query and get the list of images names. I able to produce the list:

```
 public void executeQueryImages() {
      String query1 = "some query";
        ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                rs = statement.executeQuery(query1);
                images = new ArrayList<String>();
                   while (rs.next()) {
                     Events ev = new Events();
                     ev.setImagename(rs.getString("simagename"));
                     String Imagename = ev.getImagename();
                     System.out.println("path:::"+Imagename);
                     images.add(Imagename);                 
                }
              }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(statement);
                DBUtil.close(connection);
            }
        }
         public List<String> getImages() {
            return images;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess here since I do not know how does your `Image` look like.

Here you return a list of images:

```
public List<Image> getImages() {
    return images;
}
```

But here you use it as if it was `String`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{imageBean.images}" var="image">
     <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{image}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

You see, the `ui:repeat` loops through the `List<Image>` you return from `getImages()`, but what you need is `String` (the image name). So in case you don't have a method in your `Image` to return the image name, you will likely need one.

```
/* this assumes you have field imageName in your Image class */
public String getImageName() {
    return this.imageName;
}
```

And then you could modify the page code to something like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{imageBean.images}" var="image">
     <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{image.imageName}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

**UPDATE**

A word of warning - I can see in your code you are mixing JSF and PrimeFaces components to build your page. While this is generally not a problem, there are some differences in behavior - for example, `p:commandButton` provided by PrimeFaces by default issues Ajax requests, but `h:commandButton` just reloads the whole page unless you explicitly enable Ajax for it.

So the comment from *malaguna* about not updating your `p:imageSwitch` would be valid only if you used `p:commandButton`. In addition, you seem to have typo in the button's `action` attribute - the left curly brace is missing. So it could look like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Display Images" update="switchComponent"
    action="#{imageBean.executeQueryImages}" />
```

**UPDATE #2**

There seems to be some problem with PrimeFaces 4.0 - if I open the browser console and reload the page, I can see message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`, coming from `imageswitch.js`

If you are able to switch to 5.2, the code you have in your question should work as expected - you just add two buttons to start/stop the slideshow:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnPlay" widgetVar="btnPlayWidget"
    type="button" value="Start"
    onclick="PF('switcher2').getJQ().cycle('fade'); PF('btnPlayWidget').disable(); PF('btnStopWidget').enable();" />

<p:commandButton id="btnStop" widgetVar="btnStopWidget"
    type="button" value="Stop" disabled="true"
    onclick="PF('switcher2').getJQ().cycle('stop'); PF('btnStopWidget').disable(); PF('btnPlayWidget').enable();" />
```

The `cycle('fade')` starts the slideshow using the given effect (you can supply any supported effect there).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, I edited code simply changed List<Image>(it is not required) to List<String>, working but only first image of the list is displayed but not the slide show. I have to select the value from drop down list and related id is passed to sql query to get all images based on id. I should play slideshow of those images with play and pause button(this is my requirement).

Comment: There seems to be some problem with PrimeFaces 4.0 - if I open the browser console and reload the page, I can see message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`, coming from `imageswitch.js` ... any chance for you to upgrade to 5.2?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more information on how to start/stop the slideshow in 5.2 - unfortunately it seems to be not working in 4.0, most likely due to the error we can observe in the console.

Comment: I upgraded to 5.2 and got the output. Thank you so much @Sva.Mu

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one thing clear, your `commandButton` is configured by default, that is, using ajax, but it is not updating your `imageSwitch` component.

You have to give an `id` to your `imageSwitch` component, and then update it from `commandButton`.

Something like:

```
<h:commandButton 
   value="Display Images" update="switchComponent"
   action="#imageBean.executeQueryImages}" />

<div id="slider">
  <p:imageSwitch  id="switchComponent"
      widgetVar="switcher2" effect="none"
      slideshowSpeed="100" slideshowAuto="false" >

     <ui:repeat value="#{imageBean.images}" var="image">
         <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/#{image}" />
    </ui:repeat>
  </p:imageSwitch>
</div>
```

Then you have to be if you are managing correctly images. It is not clear to me how are you doing, so, if changing the code as suggested is not sufficient to solve your problem, you will have to give us more info.

Comment: <p:imageSwitch ....... >
  <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/nature1.jpg" />
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/nature2.jpg" />
 </p:imageSwitch> ... the above is also not working, it simply displays the first image but not the slideshow. @malaguna thanks for the reply but it didn't help me.